# Check whether all records have the same value in a field?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select count(*) from step where job_id =31 ;
select count(*) from step where job_id =31 and status =2;
```

These are two queries. I want to know if `count1` and `count2` are equal in a single query

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) as jobCount,
       sum(status = 2) as statusCount,
       count(*) - sum(status = 2) as countDifference,
       (count(*) - sum(status = 2)) = 0 as isEqual
from step 
where job_id = 31;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `status` is not `NULL`, why not just count the ones that are not "2"?

```
select ( sum(status <> 2) = 0 ) as all_are_2
from step
where job_id = 31;
```

Or, if you want to handle `NULL`s:

```
select ( sum(not status <=> 2) = 0 ) as all_are_2
from step
where job_id = 31;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `COUNT(*)`, by using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select not exists (
  select 1 from step
  where job_id = 31 and status <> 2
) as equal_counters
```

This will return `1` if all rows with `job_id = 31` have `status = 2`, else it will return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know if its equal without knowing the count value, check the existence of status different than 2 is more logical :

```
select count(*) from step where job_id = 31 and status <> 2
```

If you need the value :

```
select count(*), sum(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) 
from step where jod_id = 31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (COUNT(*) - sum(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'Not Equal' ELSE 'Equal' END
FROM step 
WHERE job_id = 31
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a conditional aggregation as

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) StatusCnt,
       COUNT(*) Cnt
FROM Step
WHERE job_id =31;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are interested in knowing that there are certain rows which has `job_id` value 31, but `status` not equal to 2, then you can take the benefit of `LIMIT 1` clause. It will be more performant than using `Count(..)`; as `LIMIT 1` will stop executing at the first matching row.

```
SELECT 1 AS Row_Having_Status_NotEqual_2
FROM step
WHERE job_id = 31
  AND status <> 2
LIMIT 1
```

Above query will return one row with value `1` if there is any row with status not equal to 2 for job_id 31. On the other hand, if it returns no rows, all the rows are having status equal to 2 for job_id 31